# Proving according to Cauchy criterion that an alternating harmonic series with factorial denominator converges.

Tags: convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

I need to prove according to Cauchy's criterion that the sequence:

$a_n = 1 - \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!} - ......... + \frac{1}{(2n-1)!} - \frac{1}{(2n)!} $

converges. but I got stuck with the negative and positive terms of the sequence, I thought about triangle inequality but also didn't work. can someone give me some tips for solving this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
|a_{n+m}-a_n|&\le \frac{1}{(2n+1)!} + \frac{1}{(2n+2)!}+\dots+\frac{1}{(2(n+m)-1)!}+\frac{1}{(2(n+m))!}\le \\
&\le \frac{1}{(2n)(2n+1)} + \frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)} + \dots + \frac{1}{(2n+2m-2)(2n+2m-1)}+\\\
&+\frac{1}{(2n+2m-1)(2n+2m)}\le \\
&=\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{2n+1} + \frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+2}+\dots+ \frac{1}{2n+2m-2}-\frac{1}{2n+2m-1} +\\&+ \frac{1}{2n+2m-1}-\frac{1}{2n+2m}=\\
&=\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{2n+2m} \le \frac{1}{2n}
\end{align}

Comment: but I didn't get from first line how the negative terms disappeared !

Comment: Actually, they didn't disappear, they are just assigned positive sign from the triangle inequality $|x-y|\le|x|+|y|$

Comment: I know that $|x−y|=>||x|-|y||$ , right? but how did u suppose that this is also true ?

Comment: simple $|x-y|=|x+(-y)|\le|x|+|-y|=|x|+|y|$